# Create Read only user in Mongo DB Instance for a particular database

Tags: mongodb, security, database

I have created a user "**mongo01testro**" in the **mongo01test** database.

```
use mongo01test 
db.addUser( "mongo01testro", "pwd01", true );
db.system.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53xyz"), "user" : "mongo01testro", "readOnly" : true, "pwd" : "b9eel61" }
```

When I logged in from another session as this newly created user,
I am able to insert documents into the collection which is strange.

I am looking to do the following:

1. Create 2 separate users one for read only and one for read write for
   each database.
2. Create an **admin** user which have sysadmin/dba access to all the
   databases in MongoDB instance used for Backup/Recovery or admin
   purpose.

Please kindly help.

Regards,
Parag

Comment: Could you please also send how you are connecting?

Comment: Have you created an [administrative user](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) in the `admin` database?  If there are no users in the `admin` database you will still be able to connect via the [localhost exception](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#authenticate-with-full-administrative-access-via-localhost).  The localhost exception is available to allow you to set up your first administrative user when `mongod` is started with auth enabled.

Comment: Thanks Stennie for your reply. I have done following // Create admin user
use admin
db.addUser('root', 'strong_password');

// Read only user
use dbforuser1
db.addUser('user1', 'user1_pass', true);
When logged in as user1 still it allows me to write . Please kindly help.

Comment: Please guide me if I am missing any step.

Answer (score 17):

You forgot --auth to enable

Create Users

```
// ensure that we have new db, no roles, no users
use products
db.dropDatabase()

// create admin user
use products
db.createUser({
    "user": "prod-admin",
    "pwd": "prod-admin",
    "roles": [
        {"role": "clusterAdmin", "db": "admin" },
        {"role": "readAnyDatabase", "db": "admin" },
    "readWrite"
    ]},
    { "w": "majority" , "wtimeout": 5000 }
)

// login via admin acont in order to create readonly user
// mongo --username=prod-admin --password=prod-admin products
db.createUser({
    "user": "prod-r",
    "pwd": "prod-r",
    "roles": ["read"]
})
```

Enable auth:

```
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf # edit file
    # Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
    #noauth = true
    auth = true
sudo service mongod restart # reload configuiration
```

Check write restriction:

```
# check if write operation for readonly user
$ mongo --username=prod-r --password=prod-r products
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: products
> db.laptop.insert({"name": "HP"})
WriteResult({
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 13,
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on products to execute command { insert: \"laptop\", documents: [ { _id: ObjectId('53ecb7115f0bfc61d8b1113e'), name: \"HP\" } ], ordered: true }"
    }
})

# check write operation for admin user
$ mongo --username=prod-admin --password=prod-admin products
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: products
> db.laptop.insert({"name": "HP"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

# check read operation for readonly user    
$ mongo --username=prod-r --password=prod-r products
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: products
> db.laptop.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ecb54798da304f99625d05"), "name" : "HP" }
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB changed the way it handles users in versions >= 2.2 and 2.6 and if you are updating mongodb you will have to [Upgrade User Authorization Data to 2.6 Format](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/).

In [versions < 2.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.addUser/) (legacy) you use the `db.addUser(username, password, readOnly)` function as @Hüseyin BABAL suggested. If you are using version > 2.2 or 2.6 you have a lot more control over what you can do with roles and privileges.

So assuming you use mongo v > 2.6 you can create something like:

```
use admin

db.createUser({
    user: "myUsername",
    pwd: "mypwd",
    roles: [{
        role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        db: "admin"
    }]
})

db.addUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [{
        role: "readWrite",
        db: "myDBName"
    }]
})
```

You can use the [Build in Roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) or you can even [create custom roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/createRole/).

So as you can see you clearly have a lot more options when using v > 2.6 when it comes to authentication and role management.

Answer (score 1):

if the Access control is enabled on the MongoDB deployment, Then you should login by authenticating to the relevant database with admin user (or user with userAdmin role) which you want to control the access. to do that

```
mongo <db_name> -u <user_name> -p <user_password>
```

ex: `mongo mongo01test -u admin -p admin_paaswrod`

then execute the following query to **create a read only user** for current connected database,

```
db.createUser({user:"user_name",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"read", db:"db_name"}]});
```

ex:`db.createUser({user:"user_rd",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"read", db:"mongo01test"}]});`

create a **user with both readWrite access**,

```
db.createUser({user:"user_name",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"readWrite", db:"db_name"}]});
```

ex:`db.createUser({user:"user_rw",pwd:"pass_rw",roles:[{role:"readWrite", db:"mongo01test"}]});`

to create a **user with admin privileges,**

```
use admin;
db.createUser({user:"admin_user_name",pwd:"password", roles:[{role:"dbAdmin", db:"admin"},{role:"readWriteAnyDatabase", db:"admin"},{role:"backup", db:"admin"},{role:"restore", db:"admin"}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my scneario;

```
// Create admin user
use admin
db.addUser('root', 'strong_password');

// Read only user
use dbforuser1
db.addUser('user1', 'user1_pass', true);

// Read / Write access
use dbforuser2
db.addUser('user2', 'user2_pass');
```

If you want to login to dbforuser1

```
use dbforuser1
db.auth('user1', 'user1_pass')
```

Comment: Please confirm the reason why we need to create root user in admin. I assume that's required if we are creating read only or read write user.

Comment: You said that "Create admin user which have sysadmin/dba access to all the databases in Mongodb instance used for Backup/Recovery or admin purpose", that is why added it there

Comment: I am still able to write or insert documents when logged in as read only user. Please advise.

Comment: Worked as you expected?

Comment: mongo -u user02ro -p test02 server_ipaddress/databasename    which connects as able to read and write even though its read only user